# Scraping with Python and ViewState

Tags: python, c#, asp.net, web-scraping

Until just a couple of weeks ago i was able to get the json data from a website after performing some post requests

```
payload = {'NumDossier': numCase_com, 'idJuridiction': numJuri, 'typeDossier': "DP"}
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

Now i am getting this strange HTML on every post request

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./getJuridiction1instance" id="form1">
        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZDDGgir+XqoIRtkvd//GurKfYTbq8hIisZRyOefPLUDj" />
        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="79390B9D" />
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When inspecting the newtwork on chrome, in no time it sends `__VIEWSTATE or __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR`, i spent two days trying to figure out what i am doing wrong but nothing. (I am no expert in ASP.Net)

PS: I get the same result with postman

Comment: This are saved information for post back only. What did you expect to get ?

Comment: On the browser i get json data which is what i want and was the result until two weeks ago, i would like to know if there is a way to get past this page on Postman at least. Thank you so much @Aristos for answering.

Comment: Do you get the data with post back ? - From what I understand the page either not working any more, or have some protection to not get any more data - or if you make postback you have to send also that input with viewstate back

Comment: it's working now i just had to add session to the python request, Thanks again @Aristos